# slickgrid row sorting and deleting works not properly after adding new rows

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, slickgrid

how to make slickgrid to work properly after updating data?

when my grid is created for the first time - deleting and moving of rows works ok. when i try to add row via separate form, the request is sent to server, and if addition of new element was successful, the updated data is received and slickgrid is updated using this:

```
grid.setData(data);
grid.invalidate();
grid.render();
```

grid is rendered properly, that is i see it (including all new rows passed with new data just received from server). when i try to reorder rows - something goes wrong as if one row, that was just added to new received data, does not exist.

[Here my current testing implementation](http://crm.it-aces.com/slick/)

and even more strange things happen when i try to delete rows (moving to recycle bin).

it seems as if grid is rebuilt using new data (visually), but in reality contains or links to old data. how to correct that mistake?

thanx for the answer and help!